# Telerik Ajax RadCombobox CheckAllCheck Event not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, telerik

I am using RadCombobox in Telerik Ajax and what I would like to do is to force users must at least select 1 item, so I try to prevent user to uncheck item when it is the only checked item.

Problem is that when I enable the `EnableCheckAllItemsCheckBox` to true, there will be a `Check ALL` option by default, and users can first check all items, then uncheck all items, which is what I am trying to prevent.

First I have find this client event:

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/client-side-programming/events/onclientcheckallchecked

However it needs Version 2013+, **while I am using 2012.1.411**, so it does not work out.

Then I found this server event which probably provide same functionality:

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/server-side-programming/checkallcheck

Now my problem is, I cannot find this server side event either!

The document did not say which version of the framework needed to use this event, I wonder **Is there any reference / document listing what version of the framework support what kind of methods/events of each control**?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? You allow them to check all but not un-check all ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know is this what you want....

To get or trigger CheckAll in RadComboBox event in clientside use this...

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcb" runat="server" EnableCheckAllItemsCheckBox="true" CheckBoxes="true" OnClientLoad="onChangingInCheckAll">
        <Items>
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="a" />
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="b" />
            <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="c" />
        </Items>
    </telerik:RadComboBox>

    <telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="rsb" runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function onChangingInCheckAll() {
                $telerik.$('.rcbCheckAllItems').click(function () {
                    // Alert Testing
                    alert('a');

                    // Do your stuff
                });
            }

        </script>
    </telerik:RadScriptBlock>
```

Comment: Yes this is what I want and how I finally achieve it (just before a few mins you posted it)...But indeed what I wanted to know is that, is there any reference that which version of Telerik Framework includes what functions of each controls...Also why I cannot just use `checkallcheck` event as the document stated? (Still upvoted as yes it can solve my situation :-] )

Comment: @shole I don't have any reference for this. I just get this solution because i'm having the problem with it. Due to when i click check all checkbox doesn't enabled my button